# CPU Time Limit Exceeded Trying to Email 2000 Contacts

Tags: apex, dml, loop, cpulimit, timeout

I have a junction object called AccountContactRelation which is linked to both the Contact and Account objects.  I am trying to sort through the accounts, and for each one, add all the related contacts to the "To" line of an email.  The email is then to be sent for each account.

This works on a smaller scale, but when I try to expand to my list of about 2000 accounts, I get a CPU time out error on the flow calling this apex class.  I am aware nested loops greatly increase the processing time but I am not sure how to do this without one.  Is there another way to write the code in my nested for loop?

Thanks!

```
List<AccountContactRelation> ACRList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, ContactId, 
                                                Contact.Enrollment_Is_Completed__c, 
                                                Contact.Enrollment_Reporting_Period__c,
                                                Contact.OOSLP_Is_Completed__c, 
                                                Contact.OOSLP_Reporting_Period__c
                                     FROM AccountContactRelation
                                     WHERE IsActive = True 
                                     AND IsEmailBounced__c = False
                                     AND HasOptedOutOfEmail__c = False
                                     AND (Roles = 'Primary Contact'
                                          OR Roles INCLUDES('Data Report Recipient'))
                                     AND Roles EXCLUDES('State Portal Entity Representative')
                                     AND Contact.Enrollment_Reporting_Period__c = '2021'
                                     AND Contact.OOSLP_Reporting_Period__c = '2021'
                                     AND (Contact.Enrollment_Is_Completed__c = False
                                          OR Contact.OOSLP_Is_Completed__c = False)
                                     ];  
        
        Set<String> usedAccountIds = new Set<String>();
        Integer emailCount = 0;
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allEmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for(Integer i=0; i<ACRList.size(); i++){          
            String whatID;
            String currentAccountId = ACRList[i].AccountId;
            if(usedAccountIds.contains(currentAccountId)==false){
                whatId = currentAccountId;
                //get related contacts     
                List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>();

                for(Integer j=0; j<ACRList.size(); j++){
                    if(ACRList[j].AccountId == currentAccountId){
                        toAddresses.add(ACRList[j].ContactId);
                    }
                }
                
                String contactId = ACRList[i].ContactId;
  
                usedAccountIds.add(currentAccountId);
                
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setWhatId(whatID);            
                mail.setTargetObjectId(contactId);
                mail.setTemplateId(template.Id);
                mail.setHtmlBody(template.HtmlValue);
                mail.setTreatBodiesAsTemplate(true);
                mail.setSubject(template.Subject);  
                if(owea.get(0).Id != null){
                    mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
                }
                mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);     
                System.debug('To: '+ toAddresses);
                allEmails.add(mail);
                emailCount++;
            }
        }
        System.debug('Email Count: ' + emailCount);
        Messaging.sendEmail(allEmails);
        System.debug('All Emails Sent');
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware that Salesforce only allows you to email [5000 e-mail addresses a day](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000312442&type=1)? With these kind a numbers you might go over that pretty quickly

Comment: delegate to a Queueable which has a 60 sec CPU time limit; the 5000 email per day limit is still relevant though

Comment: And refactor to remove the anti-pattern nested loop across ACRList via use of a Map. You will find lots of existing Q&As that explain how to handle this.

Comment: @Kasper I was under the impression a single email with multiple "To" addresses only counts as 1.  If this is the case it should be fine as this is a one-time process that would only count as 2000 of the 5000

Comment: You can find what counts under this limit at the [Messaging.singleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setToAddresses) documentation.

Comment: SingleEmailMessage says "A list of email addresses or object IDs of the contacts, leads, and users you’re sending the email to. The maximum size for this field is 4,000 bytes. The maximum total of toAddresses, ccAddresses, and bccAddresses per email is 150. All recipients in these three fields count against the limit for email sent using Apex or the API."